# Command works in terminal but not in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

If I want to delete everything in the current directory except for "myfile", I can use

```
rm -r !("myfile")
```

But if I put this in a script (called `cleanup`):

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -r !("myfile")
```

I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/tmp $ ./cleanup
./cleanup: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./cleanup: line 2: `rm -r !("file2")'
```

If I run

```
ps -p $$
```

I can see that my terminal is using bash,

```
 PID TTY          TIME CMD
1345 pts/3    00:00:02 bash
```

so I'm unclear on what the problem is.

---

*Notes:*

1. I realize that **if** the script actually worked, it would delete itself. So, my script really would be something more like: `rm -r !("cleanup"|"myfile")`, but the error message is the same either way.
2. As shown by the blockquote, this is on a Raspbian OS (9 - stretch), which is Debian based.
3. I feel like this question is bound to be a duplicate, but I can't find it. There is a similarly named [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194137/bash-command-does-not-execute-from-script-but-works-when-entered-in-terminal), but it is in regards to inheriting variables, and so doesn't address my issue.

Comment: @roaima Thanks for the edit. How did you get the spaces to work in the last code block? I worked on that for a while and couldn’t figure it out.

Comment: To format a code block indent each line with four spaces. Most easily, select it (with the mouse) and click on the `{}` button in the formatting menu. Keep use of backticks for `inline code` and you'll be fine.

Comment: @roaima I must have done that a dozen times and it wouldn’t format properly. I even tried wrapping it in a pre tag. Not sure what was going on. I must have temporarily lost my mind... Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `!(pattern-list)` pattern is an [extended glob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching). Many distros have it enabled for interactive shells, but not for non-interactive ones. You can check that with

```
$ shopt extglob
extglob         on
$ bash -c 'shopt extglob'
extglob         off
```

To fix your script, you have to turn it on: add

```
shopt -s extglob
```

at the beginning of it.

Answer (score 4):

You are using here an extented globbing feature.

From the bash `man` page:

> ```
> If  the  extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several extended pattern
> matching operators are recognized.  In the following description, a pattern-list is a list
> of  one  or more patterns separated by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or
> more of the following sub-patterns:
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>        !(pattern-list)
>               Matches anything except one of the given patterns
> ```

This shell option which can be controlled through the `shopt` command is per default enabled in interactive shells but disabled per default in non-interactive shells (scripts).

To enable it use `shopt -s extglob`.

Comment: Perfect, this worked.

Comment: According to the timestamps, it looks like Benjamin beat you by 8 seconds, but I truly appreciate the answer.